# How does Moleskine paper work?

Tags: printing, digitization

I received a [Moleskine pad and a smartpen](https://us.moleskine.com/smart-writing-system). When writing on that paper, the content is transferred to an application and can be OCRed there.

The paper looks special, with a grid of dots all over the place. My understanding is that this is some kind of guiding grid.

Surprisingly, a Google search did not show any "make your moleskine paper yourselves" entries, as if the paper was so proprietary that it was not printable.

Is this the case?

Comment: Sounds like the pen works the same way as an optical mouse.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found out how to approach this.

Moleskine sells the *Neo smartpen* as an EOM (the name is mentioned-though) and going to the web site of this pen I found [a list of downloadable PDFs](https://www.neosmartpen.com/en/ncode-pdf/) which work with the pen.

As a side not following the comments - it looks like it does not exactly works like an optical mouse because I need a specific pattern on the paper to digitalize my writing and drawing. Using a plain paper does not work.

An example of such paper (zoomed to 600%) is below

[image]